# Validating all EditText fields before enabling button?

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I have several `EditText` fields (such as **Name**, **Address**, etc.) that I want to validate/check if they are **empty** or not.  If all of them are filled, I want to set my **Enter** button to **enabled**.  If even any one of the fields are empty, I want to **disable** the Enter button.

I have written my code below but my button is **not** being enabled even after all my fields are already filled.  I'm using a bunch of boolean variables to determine whether the condition is met.

I'm not sure where I went wrong since my app runs ok but not the desired results that I want which is disabling the Enter button if one or all of my fields are empty.

My variables:

```
boolean filledName, filledAddress = false; //These variables will determine if my fields are empty or not
EditText  name, address;
Button btnEnter;
```

My onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...
//Get views from layout xml via IDs
name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
btnEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);

btnEnter.setEnabled(false); //initialize the Enter button to be disabled on Activity creation

...
```

And my Add Text Changed Listeners inside my onCreate :

```
name.addTextChangedListener (new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2){
        if (!(name.toString().trim().isEmpty()))
           filledName = true;      //if name field is NOT empty, filledName value is true
   }
   ....
   //other implemented abstract codes here
});

address.addTextChangedListener (new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2){
        if (!(address.toString().trim().isEmpty()))
           filledAddress = true;     //if address field is NOT empty, filledAddress value is true
   }
   ....
   //other implemented abstract codes here
});

//This should set the Enter button to enabled once all the boolean conditions are met
//but for some reason it's not working
if (nameFilled == true && addressFilled == true)
   btnEnter.setEnabled(true);

} //end of onCreate()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not recommend you to save a boolean, because you also have to change it to `false` when the field is empty again.

I think that is better to do this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //......

    name.addTextChangedListener (new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2){
            checkRequiredFields();
       }
    });

    address.addTextChangedListener (new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2){
            checkRequiredFields();
       }
    });

    //......
}

private void checkRequiredFields() {
    if (!name.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !address.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
       btnEnter.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
       btnEnter.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your onCreate() is called only once, when the Activity is being created. Thus the code to enable the button is run once at the start (when the fields are empty) and never seen again when those EditTexts are actually created. Those lines should be put into a separate method which can be called from within each of your TextChangedListeners. So for example, have a new method

```
private void checkFields() {
    if (nameFilled == true && addressFilled == true)
       btnEnter.setEnabled(true);
}
```

and for your listeners

```
name.addTextChangedListener (new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int i, int i1, int i2){
        if (!(name.toString().trim().isEmpty()))
           filledName = true;      //if name field is NOT empty, filledName value is true
        checkFields();

   }
```

(obviously doing the same in the other one)

Comment: I just tried your code, and while it is working I ran into another problem of if the user only enters blank whitespaces and/or they delete their entry after typing something it still enables the button.  Is there anything to prevent that?  Or somehow disabling the button back again?

Comment: All of that can be handled from methods validating the entered text. Your existing checkFields() method can disable as well as enable! If you are not happy with the text you can fail to enable in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems like yours too, I gave up after a while and did this. It won't disable your button but it won't let you go to another activity if the edit texts are empty.Don't know if this is what you're looking for but I hope it will help you! Juan Cruz Soler is right, don't save a boolean. You can do it like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
btnEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter); 
btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if ( name.getText().toString().trim().equals("") ||
                    address.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No data input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), theActivityYouWantToGo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
```